# Asking question using "welch-" in genitive case

Tags: word-usage, question

I don't know why but I couldn't create a question using welch- in genitive case. I think I must quit studying german for a while.

> die typischen Merkmale der Epoche sind oben gelistet.

This is a simple sentence about an era called "Aufklärung", I would like to add a question to this sentence and ask it. But I could not done with it using "welch-". Could you please have a look at my question if it works?

> Die typischen Merkmale welcher Epoche ist oben gelistet?
>
> Von welcher Epochen typischen Merkmale sind oben gelistet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of the fact that you are asking for more than one *Merkmal*, you need to use *sind* instead of *ist* in your first question, which is otherwise fine:

> Die typischen Merkmale welcher Epoche sind oben gelistet?

If you want to ask for more than one *Epoche* (for example, if the *Merkmale* match more than one) you can also use the same sentence structure:

> Die typischen Merkmale [wessen] sind oben gelistet?
>   Die typischen Merkmale **welcher Epochen** sind oben gelistet?

Note the plural *Epoche**n***.

The declension would be like this:

```
nom: welche Epoche  | welche Epochen
gen: welcher Epoche | welcher Epochen
dat: welcher Epoche | welchen Epochen
akk: welche Epoche  | welche Epochen
```

---

In addition and based on the comments to one of the other answers: you might want to use *aufgelistet* or *aufgeführt* instead of *gelistet*.

Comment: I'm happy almost was sentence correct, when we didn't count using singular case instead plural which was my typo.Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Neben Therins Fragen:

> Die typischen Merkmale welcher Epoche sind oben gelistet?

(Mehrzahl: *Merkmale*, also *sind gelistet*)

> Von welcher Epoche sind die typischen Merkmale oben gelistet? (Dem Zeitalter der Aufklärung.)

(Einzahl: *der Epoche*, also auch *welcher Epoche*)

sind weitere möglich:

> Die typischen Merkmale der Epoche sind an welchem Ort gelistet? (Oben.)
>
> Die typischen Merkmale der Epoche sind oben auf welche Art notiert? (Sie sind gelistet.)
>
> Welcher Art sind die Merkmale der Epoche, die oben gelistet sind? (Sie sind typischer Art.)

Aufgelistet ist auch schön, aber gelistet ist längst in den dt. Sprachgebrauch eingezogen, und da es im Ausgangssatz für die Frage steht, gehört es auch in die Frage.

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is fine when you replace ist with sind:

> Die typischen Merkmale welcher Epoche sind oben gelistet?

Your second question should be:

> Von welchen Epochen sind die typischen Merkmale oben gelistet?

Comment: Some explanation would be nice.

Comment: The first one has to be with sind because Merkmale is plural.
The second one I can not explain, I hope someone else could.

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Visit the [help] for unanswered questions about how it works. As Iris said, answers that give explanations to phenomena rather than just saying ‘it’s like that’ are generally better received here.

Comment: @Therin by the way "to listen" is Anglizismus, what is german word instead?

Comment: @Iris "von" always gets the dativ form and plural dativ (because Epochen is plural) ends in "en". That's why it's "welchen" here. The "sind" is because "Merkmale" is plural.

Comment: @Dragut "aufgelistet" or "aufgezählt" would be appropriate here. In some cases "genannt" would also work. I would go with the second one, even though there is a slight implication of having a numbered list.

Comment: @Therin, please include additional information to your answer, instead of commenting (edit butten is below your answer).

Comment: As mentioned by others, please edit your question to add the explanation, instead of posting it as a comment. Anyhow, the first sentence could be in plural, and the second sentence could also begin in "Von welcher Epoche...", i.e. singular.